# Problem with using Manipulate in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried the following example, but nothing shows up.

```
f = a*b*c*x
Manipulate[Plot[f, {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

However, if I replace f in the second line by `a*b*c*x` directly, it works. Could anyone explain why this happens, please?

(In fact, my f could be obtained by some tedious calculation and it is a long expression, so it is inappropriate to copy-paste it into the second line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Bill's detailed explanation. I think of a way to work around this with his suggestion.

```
g = a*b*c*x;
f[a_, b_, c_, x_] := Evaluate[g];
Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[g], {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: In Mathematica help page of "Manipulate", it mentions the PlotRange may vary and cause resizing and suggests using a fixed PlotRange to prevent resizing. You can check the help page to see examples. (In my case, I don't care the plot range changes.)